# how can split integers into bytes without using arithmetic in c?

Tags: c, math

I am implementing four basic arithmetic functions(add, sub, division, multiplication) in C.

the basic structure of these functions I imagined is

the program gets two operands by user using scanf,

and the program split these values into bytes and compute!

I've completed addition and subtraction,

but I forgot that I shouldn't use arithmetic functions,

so when splitting integer into single bytes,

I wrote codes like

```
    while(quotient!=0){
    bin[i]=quotient%2;
    quotient=quotient/2;
    i++;
}
```

but since there is arithmetic functions that i shouldn't use..

so i have to rewrite that splitting parts,

but i really have no idea how can i split integer into single byte without using
% or /.

Comment: Do you mean splitting into bits, rather than bytes?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about using arithmetic operators in the input-to-bits conversion. After all, you're taking advantage of a lot more arithmetic built into `scanf` to do the decimal-input-to-C-int conversion. I'd just consider this part of the input processing and worry about using or not using arithmetic once you have the array of bits.

Comment: yes this is my homework.. and i am bad at it :-(

Answer (score 1):

To access the bytes of a variable **type punning** can be used.
According to the Standard C (C99 and C11), only `unsigned char` brings certainty to perform this operation in a safe way.

This could be done in the following way:

```
typedef unsigned int myint_t;
myint_t x = 1234;
union {
  myint_t val;
  unsigned char byte[sizeof(myint_t)];
} u;
```

Now, you can of course access to the bytes of x in this way:

```
u.val = x;
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(myint_t); j++)
   printf("%d ",u.byte[j]);
```

However, as WhozCrag has pointed out, there are issues with endianness.
It cannot be assumed that the bytes are in determined order.
So, before doing any computation with bytes, your program needs to check how the endianness works.

```
#include <limits.h> /* To use UCHAR_MAX */

unsigned long int ByteFactor = 1u + UCHAR_MAX; /* 256 almost everywhere */
u.val = 0;

for (int j = sizeof(myint_t) - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)
  u.val = u.val * ByteFactor + j;
```

Now, when you print the values of u.byte[], you will see the order in that bytes are arranged for the type `myint_t`.
The less significant byte will have value 0.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 32 bit integers (if not the case then just change the sizes) there are more approaches:

1. **BYTE pointer**

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   int x; // your integer or whatever else data type
   BYTE *p=(BYTE*)&x;
   x=0x11223344;
   printf("%x\n",p[0]);
   printf("%x\n",p[1]);
   printf("%x\n",p[2]);
   printf("%x\n",p[3]);
   ```

   - just get the address of your data as BYTE pointer
   - and access the bytes directly via 1D array
2. **union**

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   union
    {
    int x; // your integer or whatever else data type
    BYTE p[4]; 
    } a;
   a.x=0x11223344;
   printf("%x\n",a.p[0]);
   printf("%x\n",a.p[1]);
   printf("%x\n",a.p[2]);
   printf("%x\n",a.p[3]);
   ```

   - and access the bytes directly via 1D array

[notes]

- if you do not have `BYTE` defined then change it for `unsigned char`
- with ALU you can use not only `%,/` but also `>>,&` which is way faster but still use arithmetics
- now depending on the platform endianness the output can be `11,22,33,44` of `44,33,22,11` so you need to take that in mind (especially for code used in multiple platforms)
- you need to handle sign of number, for unsigned integers there is no problem
- but for signed the C uses 2'os complement so it is better to separate the sign before spliting like:

  ```
  int s;
  if (x<0) { s=-1; x=-x; } else s=+1;
  // now split ...
  ```

**[edit2] logical/bit operations**

- `x<<n`,`x>>n` - is bit shift left and right of x by n bits
- `x&y` - is bitwise logical and (perform logical AND on each bit separately)
- so when you have for example 32 bit `unsigned int` (called `DWORD`) yu can split it to BYTES like this:

  ```
  DWORD  x; // input 32 bit unsigned int
  BYTE a0,a1,a2,a3; // output BYTES a0 is the least significant a3 is the most significant
  x=0x11223344;
  a0=DWORD((x    )&255); // should be 0x44
  a1=DWORD((x>> 8)&255); // should be 0x33
  a2=DWORD((x>>16)&255); // should be 0x22
  a3=DWORD((x>>24)&255); // should be 0x11
  ```
- this approach is not affected by endianness
- but it uses ALU
- the point is shift the bits you want to position of `0..7` bit and mask out the rest
- the `&255` and `DWORD()` overtyping is not needed on all compilers but some do weird stuff without them especially on signed variables like char or int
- `x>>n` is the same as `x/(pow(2,n))=x/(1<<n)`
- `x&((1<<n)-1)` is the same as `x%(pow(2,n))=x%(1<<n)`
- so `(x>>8)=x/256` and `(x&255)=x%256`

Comment: Careful; the output the `union` produces can (and in most value cases, will) vary significantly depending on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the platform this runs on.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes I agree therefore I wrote  0x11223344 to input so it is visible in output  what order used platform has. But yes I could mention that in notes (so +1). Still why down vote? instead of providing different answer without ALU use ...?

Comment: Question is tagged with "c" only, not c++.

Comment: reedited the answer (changed cout for printf, and added some notes)

Comment: could you tell me more about using & and >>?